# Why does ss-id persist on logout and re-login?

Tags: servicestack

I am having some cross-session identity contamination in rare cases.
Chasing this down I noticed something that doesn't make sense to me.

I login as user x in my ui (using a CORS servicestack server) and I observe the ss-id cookie value.

I logout using auth/logout and then login as a different user and the ss-id cookie value remains the same, but my session values (identity etc) in the server seem fine.

Is this normal?  Isn't the ss-id cookie a session cookie and hence should not stay the same across different sessions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The browser may retain the session cookie until the tab or window is closed. You may want to delete the session cookie from the client side on logout and invalidate it from the server side upon logout.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary `ss-id` and permanent `ss-pid` Session cookies are explained on the [Session wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions).

If you close your browser session your temporary `ss-id` will be lost and the next time you access ServiceStack a new one will be generated. The `ss-pid` permanent cookies survives browser restarts.

Logging out just removes the Server Session stored against those cookies (i.e. essentially making them an anonymous user), it doesn't remove the cookies themselves.

Comment: Ok - this makes sense - if I logout and relogin as a different user from the same browser (without closing) is it possible that the session is going to get confused since the same session id is being sent from the browser for a different user?

Comment: The session cookies are just an identifier to the Server Session, when you logout, the Session is gone, so the ids don't point to anything just as if they session ids were newly generated, i.e. there's no trace left of the original session.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you're saying and perhaps I am being dense, but when I logout and login in the same browser window and tab, whether with the same user or different user, I see the same ss-id in the cookie.  If the server side session's association with the prior session id is recycled, how is it that I am seeing the same ss-id in the browser after prior session has ended?  Shouldn't servicestack notice that the session id being passed is an expired one and create a new session id and send it back to the the client as the ss-id?

Comment: @t316 the sessionId is just an opaque string identifier, as mentioned earlier the session that's stored at that identifier is removed on logout. The "sessionId itself doesn't expire", it's just a string, it either points to a valid session or it doesn't. On logout the session is removed from the cache and the session Id no longer points to anything, in the same way that a new generated identifier doesn't point to anything. ServiceStack doesn't care what the string is, whether its been used before or what it used to point to, only if it points to a valid session at the time the request is made.